# Get full path image into input file

Tags: javascript, jquery, upload

I want get the full path image from input file for show image preview and use for example **attr** of jquery for insert this into scr to this temporal image path , for example i think in that

```
var filePath = $(this).val();
console.log(filePath);

jQuery('#preview').attr("src",""+img_p);
```

The problem i don´t know how i can get this temporal path from input file for show and insert this path for the preview image until send to upload in the system

Thank´s , Regards

Comment: I think if you can retrieve the absolute URL of the image, using regex you can cut out parts of the url which should leave you with the relative part.

Answer (score 0):

MOZILLA DEVELOPER NETWORK show us an example to do that:

```
<input type="file" id="fileElem" multiple accept="image/*" style="display:none" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">
<a href="#" id="fileSelect">Select some files</a> 
<div id="fileList">
  <p>No files selected!</p>
</div>

<script>
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

var fileSelect = document.getElementById("fileSelect"),
    fileElem = document.getElementById("fileElem"),
    fileList = document.getElementById("fileList");

fileSelect.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  if (fileElem) {
    fileElem.click();
  }
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent navigation to "#"
}, false);

function handleFiles(files) {
  if (!files.length) {
    fileList.innerHTML = "<p>No files selected!</p>";
  } else {
    var list = document.createElement("ul");
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      var li = document.createElement("li");
      list.appendChild(li);

      var img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(files[i]);
      img.height = 60;
      img.onload = function(e) {
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
      }
      li.appendChild(img);

      var info = document.createElement("span");
      info.innerHTML = files[i].name + ": " + files[i].size + " bytes";
      li.appendChild(info);
    }
    fileList.appendChild(list);
  }
}
</script>
```

[HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example.3a.c2.a0Showing_thumbnails_of_user-selected_images) the Mozilla DOC.

[HERE](http://css-tricks.com/local-previews-of-images/) some problem to do that.